# Add '\' character to a string

Tags: c++, string

I want to store in a string variable this bash command:

```
find /Users/memmaker6501/Desktop/ -name "*\[*\]*" -type d >> busqueda.txt
```

But I obtained an error with the sequence `\]`

There is a way to store the `\]` in the string ?

Comment: @YuHao As I understand it, he wants to store that command as a C++ std::string or `const char*`.

Comment: @NikosC That still doesn't warrant the [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I think it does, because it's about how to escape quotes in C++, not in bash. Well, at least that's how I understood the question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a `\` before your special characters. Like this `"find /Users/memmaker6501/Desktop/ -name \"*\\[*\\]*\" -type d >> busqueda.txt"`

Comment: That's save my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Backslashes and double quotes should be escaped with backslashes, like so:

```
"find /Users/memmaker6501/Desktop/ -name \"*\\[*\\]*\" -type d >> busqueda.txt"
```

[Escape sequences in C++ strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape):

```
Escape
sequence    Description                     Representation

\'          single quote                    byte 0x27
\"          double quote                    byte 0x22
\?          question mark                   byte 0x3f
\\          backslash                       byte 0x5c
\0          null character                  byte 0x00
\a          audible bell                    byte 0x07
\b          backspace                       byte 0x08
\f          form feed - new page            byte 0x0c
\n          line feed - new line            byte 0x0a
\r          carriage return                 byte 0x0d
\t          horizontal tab                  byte 0x09
\v          vertical tab                    byte 0x0b
\nnn        arbitrary octal value           byte nnn
\xnn        arbitrary hexadecimal value     byte nn
\unnnn      arbitrary Unicode value.        code point U+nnnn
\Unnnnnnnn  arbitrary Unicode value.        code point U+nnnnnnnn
```

Answer (score 3):

C++11 has raw string literals to simplify creating complex string expressions.

```
R"***(find /Users/memmaker6501/Desktop/ -name "*\[*\]*" -type d >> busqueda.txt)***"
```